# WinDbg callstack hexadecimal offset

Tags: stack, windbg

what does the hexadecimal value (with the +) behind the function name stands for ?

```
00 012ff668 7795aa24 ntdll_778f0000!LdrInitShimEngineDynamic+0x726
01 012ff8a0 77956e84 ntdll_778f0000!WinSqmSetDWORD64+0x14e4
02 012ff8f4 77956cd0 ntdll_778f0000!LdrInitializeThunk+0x1c4
03 012ff8fc 00000000 ntdll_778f0000!LdrInitializeThunk+0x10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These numbers [indicate offset from the nearest resolved function entry](http://forum.sysinternals.com/windbg-function-plus-offset_topic23574.html). The higher number `WinSqmSetDWORD64+0x14e4` indicates you have symbol loading issues and Windbg used the [export table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/z4zxe9k8.aspx) to get the function name and generated the large offset based on the function names it got from the export table.

Comment: If the symbols are off very far, note that the function name like `WinSqmSetDWORD64` may be absolutely incorrect and misleading. I see that often for `DllUnregisterServer` when a DLL is not being unregistered at all.