# what means bytes in the stack trace of c++ application

Tags: c++, windows, windbg

i got a crash dump and a stack trace for an app on windows 2012 r2 and the stack trace line ends up with function + N bytes.
What bytes / offset means? Could it be used to identify the line in the source code of the function that crashed? For example below what means 6092 bytes? It is not the line number

I see that in other application crash the offset is in hexal base.

app.exe caused exception C0000005 (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION) at 000000009067B6BC

Register dump:

Crash dump successfully written to file 'C:\Program Files\App\appcrash.dmp'

Stack Trace:
0x000000009067B6BC (0xA95C44A0 0xA86FCE60 0xA95C44A0 0x00000008) app.exe, appFunction1()+6092 bytes

Comment: You should be able to produce a PDB file for your app that can be used while debugging the dump to get much clearer information.

Comment: The debugger tries to guess which specific function caused the crash.  It uses the PDB file first, if missing or out-of-date then it has to fall back to exported functions.  +6092 tells you that it doesn't have a good PDB and that you can't assume it was not actually appFunction1.  Focus on getting that PDB, a non-stripped one so you can get source file and line number info as well.  You typically have to rebuild and redeploy so files will match.

Comment: it is the nearest symbol that windbg was able to locate.  if you issue the ln (list nearest command) windbg will show you this symbol (appfun1)  and offset bigger than few hundred byte are suspect always

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WinDbg callstack hexadecimal offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40565162/windbg-callstack-hexadecimal-offset)